# Exception handling when overridden method does not throw any exception

Tags: java, exception

**Short form:** How do you throw exceptions (or do nice, clean exception handling; or at least dirtily force execution to stop) when the overridden method doesn't throw exceptions?

**Context:** We have a license for a piece of proprietary software that can be automated using Java "macros". A user-defined macro must be of this form:

```
public class MyMacro extends SoftwareMacro {
    public void execute() {
        // user code goes here
    }
}
```

i.e. a class that extents `SoftwareMacro` and that has a method called `execute` that overrides the base class' `execute`. The contents of this overriding `execute` are what gets... well... executed when the macro is "played".

But the overridden `execute` method apparently does not throw any exceptions.

```
execute() in com.mycompany.mypackage.MyMacro cannot implement execute() in 
somesoftware.base.SoftwareMacro
overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception
```

Maybe this is naïve, but while developing I usually like to have the appropriate exception type bubble up to the top and force execution to stop, so that I can see them and go on to debug. This is apparently not an option here.

Should I resort to throwing `RuntimeException` instead? (since `RuntimeException` does not need to be specified) That feels a bit sloppy, and a "violation in spirit" of the base class method contracy.

P.S. No, I can't change the source code of the overriden `execute` method.

Comment: The clean way would be to have a centralised 'exception' handler which would detect the 'raising' of an exception from inside your overriding method and halt application execution.  The pragmatic way would be to throw a RuntimeException.

Comment: @DaveHowes - yes, you're misreading it, sorry. Java requires an overriding method's exception specification to be a proper subset of the overridden method's; an empty set is a proper subset of course. You're not required to throw the same exceptions your superclass does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the intent is that each `SoftwareMacro` do all its own error handling. Use a big `try` around your whole `execute()` method if need be, but don't let any exceptions escape. Do whatever cleanup you need to do inside your execute method, and possibly print an error message for the user, if they provide a way to do that.

You should examine all the APIs they provide -- perhaps there's an error reporting facility you're supposed to use.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on what the "Macro player" does if it encounters a runtime exception, and on what you want to happen.

If it doesn't handle it at all, but you don't care, throw a RuntimeException.

If it handles them properly, throw a RuntimeException.

If it doesn't handle them properly, and you don't want it to fail miserably, then catch the exceptions that might happen in your execute method, and handle them as you feel is the best: show an error dialog box, output an error message, log some error in the logs...

Answer (score 1):

"Should" implies there's a right answer, which IMO there isn't do what meets your needs.

If the system can tolerate a runtime exception, and it meets your needs, why not?

Not that you have a choice, since you can't throw a checked exception.

(Checked exceptions seem like a failed experiment to me, although I understand the motivation.)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to adopt good habits and good practice, which is what was implied by "should". I'm looking for something more far-sighted than satisfying my immediate needs.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Good habits are... good, but only when the meet the needs of what you're trying to do. Clearly the writers believe that all error handling should be done within the macro, and that *may* be appropriate--it depends on the context. By not providing any framework-specific exception signature, however, they've locked you in. Consider what Ernest said--is there a framework mechanism for reporting errors? Also, even if the system doesn't actually *halt*, you can still log exceptions for examination.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the `execute` code doesn't absorb the exception, it will still throw it if one is encountered. If the kind of exceptions thrown are either `RuntimeException` or sub-classes of `RuntimeException` they don't need to be explicitly declared, mostly because the compiler doesn't enforce their declaration since (as the name implies) they only happen at runtime, and cannot *necessarily* be predicted at compile time.

If, however, the `execute` method, which you've said you can't modify, absorbs the exception, and doesn't indicate that exception via a log entry, return value, or some kind of `RuntimeException` I think you're out of luck.

I would agree with Ernest that it appears that the intent is that the `execute` method do all its own exception handling.

NOTE: Overridden method signatures don't need to match exactly when it comes to the exceptions they throw - just the name, return type, and list & type of variables.

Comment: Well, no, not match exactly, but overriding methods are restricted to throwing a subset (and never a superset) of the overriden method's specified exceptions.